# How to use Timestamp Data in Building Naive Bayes model in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, timestamp, naivebayes

I have a Dataset, with Timestamp as one of the column with the format 09/07/2016 23:58.

I'm trying to apply Naive Bayes on this Data, and i'm facing the below error. Please let me know how to use this Data in my model

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 12/06/2016 23:59

Comment: what is `df['Timestamp'].dtype?`

Comment: Are you sure  `dtype` of your date column is `datetime`? test it by `df.dtypes`. If not, it seems there are some bad data - use `pd.to_datetime(df.date, erors='coerce')`

Comment: for convert values to `NaT` if cannot be converted to datetime .

Comment: It is of the type object, how do i convert to Datetime? It is throwing an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert bad not parseable values to `NaT`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['12/06/2016 23:59','12/06/2016 23:59', 'a']})
print (df)
               date
0  12/06/2016 23:59
1  12/06/2016 23:59
2                 a


print (pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce'))
0   2016-12-06 23:59:00
1   2016-12-06 23:59:00
2                   NaT
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

For test bad values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - return all rows where is `NaT`:

```
print (df[pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce').isnull()])
  date
2    a
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. Since I'm new to python, I'm having one more query. Now that I have got this column, how do i append it to my original Dataframe
Or is there anyway, the existing Dataframe will be updated

Comment: thank you for accepting! use `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, errors='coerce')` or `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 0):

From you question it is not quite clear what you are doing but there are already couple of examples available on Internet:

- [How To Implement Naive Bayes From Scratch in Python](http://machinelearningmastery.com/naive-bayes-classifier-scratch-python/)
- [Naive Bayes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html)
- [6 Easy Steps to Learn Naive Bayes Algorithm (with code in Python)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/09/naive-bayes-explained/)

And some code pieces in SO:

- [Different types of features to train Naive Bayes in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707914/different-types-of-features-to-train-naive-bayes-in-python-pandas)
- [Unable to use Pandas and NLTK to train Naive Bayes (machine learning) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441324/unable-to-use-pandas-and-nltk-to-train-naive-bayes-machine-learning-in-python)
- [How to run naive Bayes from NLTK with Python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337714/how-to-run-naive-bayes-from-nltk-with-python-pandas)